# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, but why?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive looked at this for hours and cannot understand why Im getting the error. Ive checked the number of **`columns`** etc but for the life of me cannot figure it out. Im trying to either **`update or insert`** from one table to the other using an On **`Duplicate key update`**.
Please help with my sanity...

```
 Insert INTO `mydata`.`ZINummer` (
 `Artikelnummer: ZI-nummer`, 
 `Artikelomschrijving: naam`,
 `Artikelomschrijving: inkoophoeveelheid (aantal)`,
 `Artikelomschrijving: inkoophoeveelheid (eenheid)`,
 `Prijs: apotheekinkoop (ex. BTW)`,
 `Gm.: productnaam: GPK=generiek (code)`,
 `Gm.: productnaam: PRK=prescriptie (code)`,
 `Code: koelkast`,
 `Code: opiaat (omschrijving)`,
 `Dosering: DDD per basiseenheid product (aantal)`,
 `Alg.: productgroep (code)`,
 `Naam: productverantwoordelijke`,
 `Naam: registratiehouder`,
 `Inkoopkanaal (code)`,
 `Gm.: productnaam: GPK=generiek (omschrijving)`,
 `Gm.: productnaam: PRK=prescriptie (omschrijving)`,
 `Land van herkomst (code)`,
 `Dosering: DDD per verpakking (aantal)`,
 `Artikelomschrijving: etiketnaam`,
 `BTW (code)`
)
SELECT t.`Artikelnummer: ZI-nummer` as a,
 t.`Artikelomschrijving: naam` as b,
 t.`Artikelomschrijving: inkoophoeveelheid (aantal)` as c,
 t.`Artikelomschrijving: inkoophoeveelheid (eenheid)` as d,
 t.`Prijs: apotheekinkoop (ex. BTW)` as e,
 t.`Gm.: productnaam: GPK=generiek (code)` as f,
 t.`Gm.: productnaam: PRK=prescriptie (code)` as g,
 t.`Code: koelkast` as h,
 t.`Code: opiaat (omschrijving)` as v,
 t.`Dosering: DDD per basiseenheid product (aantal)` as j,
 t.`Alg.: productgroep (code)` as k,
 t.`Naam: productverantwoordelijke` as l,
 t.`Naam: registratiehouder` as m,
 t.`Inkoopkanaal (code)` as n,
 t.`Gm.: productnaam: GPK=generiek (omschrijving)` as o,
 t.`Gm.: productnaam: PRK=prescriptie (omschrijving)` as p,
 t.`Land van herkomst (code)` as q,
 t.`Dosering: DDD per verpakking (aantal)` as r,
 t.`Artikelomschrijving: etiketnaam`,`BTW (code)` as s,
 t.`BTW (code)` as u

FROM  mydata.totaal as t


ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`Artikelnummer: ZI-nummer` = t.a, 
`Artikelomschrijving: naam` = t.b,
`Artikelomschrijving: inkoophoeveelheid (aantal)` = t.c,
`Artikelomschrijving: inkoophoeveelheid (eenheid)` = t.d,
`Prijs: apotheekinkoop (ex. BTW)` = t.e,
`Gm.: productnaam: GPK=generiek (code)` = t.f,
`Gm.: productnaam: PRK=prescriptie (code)` = t.g,
`Code: koelkast` = t.h,
`Code: opiaat (omschrijving)` = t.v,
`Dosering: DDD per basiseenheid product (aantal)` = t.j,
`Alg.: productgroep (code)` = t.k,
`Naam: productverantwoordelijke` = t.l,
`Naam: registratiehouder` = t.m,
`Inkoopkanaal (code)` = t.n,
`Gm.: productnaam: GPK=generiek (omschrijving)` = t.o,
`Gm.: productnaam: PRK=prescriptie (omschrijving)` = t.p,
`Land van herkomst (code)` = t.q,
`Dosering: DDD per verpakking (aantal)` = t.r,
`Artikelomschrijving: etiketnaam` = t.s,
`BTW (code)` = t.u;

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: i strongly suggest using the websites search option next time https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+Column+count+doesn%27t+match+value+count+at+row+1

Comment: Are those long names seriously the names of the columns?  Normally table column names have shorter names without spaces or non-word characters.  Because you can give them aliases in the queries anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the advice raymond. I did search the website for answers and the error would suggest that there is something wrong with the formatting, because it has the same amount of fields. However, I cannot see where in my code. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms. Unfortunately its a legacy database, its all I have to work with.

Comment: "t.`Artikelomschrijving: etiketnaam`,`BTW (code)` as s", are two columns... 2:nd last row before FROM. You insert 20 columns, but select 21.

Comment: Genius!!! I was starting to think I had lost the plot. Thanks @jarlh

Comment: "I did search the website for answers and the error would suggest that there is something wrong with the formatting, because it has the same amount of fields" No your column count is really unequal.. MySQL does not lie..

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland